# Not able to configure custom hive-metastore-client in spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hive-metastore

We are facing some challenges working with spark and hive.
We need to connect to hive-metastore from spark and we have to use custom hive-metastore-client inside spark.
code snippet:

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
        .config('spark.sql.hive.metastore.version','3.1.2' ) \
        .config('spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars', 'hive-standalone-metastore-3.1.2-sqlquery.jar') \
        .config("spark.yarn.dist.jars", "hive-exec-3.1.2.jar") \
        .config('hive.metastore.uris', "thrift://localhost:9090") \
```

the above code works with inbuilt hive-metastore-client but fails with custom one with error:

**py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o79.databaseExists.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/metadata/HiveException**

**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException**

To resolve this issue, we have configured custom hive-exec in code and also tried to pass using command line:

- /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.1.2/libexec/bin/spark-submit spark-session.py --jars hive-exec-3.1.2.jar
- /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.1.2/libexec/bin/spark-submit spark-session.py --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath hive-exec-3.1.2.jar
- /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.1.2/libexec/bin/spark-submit spark-session.py --driver-class-path hive-exec-3.1.2.jar

But the issue is not resolved yet, any suggestion would help us.